# Access key value pairs in gensim dictionary

Tags: python, gensim

I am working with the gensim dictionary. For example, you can print `print(dictionary.token2id)`, as shown here https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html. I can also `print dictionary`:

`Dictionary(7 unique tokens: [u'nra', u'canon', u'deuterium', u'ion', u'facebook']...)`

How do I access the key value pairs of the dictionary object, however?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Token2id is a standard python dict. You can iterate like a standard dict:

Python 2:

```
for k, v in dictionary.token2id.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

For Python 3 use `items()`:

```
for k, v in dictionary.token2id.items():
    print(k, v)
```